# Update field in a table with values from another field from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I need to update the last 110 values ​​of the descricao_geral table with the last 110 values ​​of the relevo table

I'm doing this:

```
UPDATE descricao_geral
SET id_relevo_fk = (SELECT id_relevo FROM relevo ORDER BY id_relevo DESC LIMIT 110) 
ORDER BY id_descricao DESC
LIMIT 110
```

The error I've received:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: The subquery in your current update is not correlated, and does not make much sense.  Please add sample data for both tables which can explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @SabrinaT . . . This is a good question.  Unfortunately, your attempt to solve it doesn't really come close to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really tricky.  You need to join the tables together, but you don't have an appropriate key.

You can use variables to assign a sequential value and then use this for the `join`:

```
update descricao_geral g join
       (select (@rng := @rng + 1) as rn, g2.id_descricao
        from (select g2.* from descricao_geral g2 order by g2.id_descricao desc) g2 cross join
             (select @rng := 0) params
        limit 110
       ) g2
       on g.id_descricao = g2.id_descricao join
       (select (@rnr := @rnr + 1) as rn, r.id_relevo
        from (select r.* from relevo r order by r.id_relevo desc) r cross join
             (select @rnr := 0) params
       ) r
       on g2.rn = r.rn
   set g.id_relevo_fk = r.id_relevo;
```

Comment: Almost there. Updated with incremental values ​​but not with the last 110 values from relevo table

Comment: @SabrinaT. . . . Sometimes in MySQL, you need to do the sort in a subquery *before* assigning the variable values.  I modified the answer.